# select rows from dataTable - Issue with the values which have singlequote

Tags: select, datatable, escaping

I have a .Net `datatable`, from which I am filtering rows using a select function.

For example, assume the `datatable` as below

```
-----------------------------------
| Id | Name | Description         |
-----------------------------------
| 1  | Anish| "sachin's centuary" |
-----------------------------------
```

I search my `datatable` like this...

```
datatable.select("Description = 'sachin's centuary'")
```

However, it isn't returning any rows because of the "single quote" in description. I tried to replace the single quote with double single quote as in SQL, but this doesn't work either. Could anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have to escape the single quotes within the function call like so:

```
datatable.select("Description = 'sachin\'s centuary'")
```

Though you didn't state what language you are using.

Comment: I am using c#

How do I insert "\" before single quote in the string 'sachin's centuary'. I tried Replace function but the string after replace looks same...am not able to see any "\"

Answer (score 0):

In the following blog ...i have seen this solution
http://www.marvinpalmer.com/MarvinPalmer/post/Trouble-with-Single-Quotes-and-StringReplace().aspx

public string escapeChar(string strToEsc)
    {
        if (strToEsc.IndexOf("'") > -1)
        {
            strToEsc = strToEsc.Replace("'", @"\'"); // notice the addition of the @ symbol
        }
        return strToEsc;
   }

but its not working for me..."'" is getting replaced with "\'" :(